# Activate SSL with lighttpd on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: ssl, https, server, raspberry-pi, lighttpd

I've been looking for a while, unfortunately without resolution: **how to switch to HTTPS a lighttpd server functional in HTTP on a Raspberry Pi?**

**Important to know:** this website being connected to my router, it is accessible thanks to a dynamic DNS under a domain: *name.ddns.net* (also ports 80 and 443 are open on this router).

**Here is my process:**

- generate the keys:

```sh
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout domain.tld.key -out domain.tld.csr

openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in domain.tld.csr -signkey domain.tld.key -out domain.tld.crt
```

- combine the certificates with key:

```sh
cat domain.tld.key domain.tld.crt > domain.tld.pem
```

Here is the configuration in `lighttpd.conf`:

```sh
server.modules = (
        "mod_access",
        "mod_accesslog",
        "mod_alias",
        "mod_compress",
        "mod_redirect",
        "mod_rewrite",
)

server.document-root        = "/var/www/html"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 80 #443 with @gstrauss answer

index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"

# Log access
accesslog.filename         = "/var/log/lighttpd/access.log"

# SSL Server settings
$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
ssl.engine = "enable"
ssl.pemfile = "/etc/lighttpd/ssl/domain.tld.pem"
ssl.ca-file = "/etc/lighttpd/ssl/domain.tld.crt"
server.name = "domain.tld"
server.document-root = "/var/www/html"
ssl.use-sslv2 = "disable"
ssl.use-sslv3 = "disable"
ssl.use-compression = "disable"
ssl.honor-cipher-order = "enable"
ssl.cipher-list = "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:ECDH-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:RC4-SHA"
}
```

**And: nothing!** (after `/etc/init.d/lighttpd restart`of course), my website is still in HTTP.

Do you have a solution or an idea to test?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Succeeded!** for some reason unfortunately I don't know it was enough to transform the SSL part into:

```sh
# SSL Server settings
server.port = 443
ssl.engine = "enable"
ssl.pemfile = "/etc/lighttpd/ssl/domain.tld.pem"
ssl.ca-file = "/etc/lighttpd/ssl/domain.tld.crt"
server.name = "domain.tld"
server.document-root = "/var/www/html"
ssl.use-sslv2 = "disable"
ssl.use-sslv3 = "disable"
#ssl.use-compression = "disable"
ssl.honor-cipher-order = "enable"
ssl.cipher-list = "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:ECDH-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:RC4-SHA"
```

**Must therefore :**

1. Remove condition
2. (optional) comment on ssl compression because useless

Comment: I would recommend reviewing the [lighttpd TLS docs](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_SSL).  The config template you started with in the RPi looks a bit dated.  Half the `ssl.*` directives you are using are redundant with the defaults or no longer recommended.  Your `ssl.cipher-list` is weak.

Answer (score 0):

lighttpd listens on port 80 by default.  If want to stop listening on port 80, then tell lighttpd to listen on port 443 by default:

`server.port = 443`

Comment: Thanks @gstrauss ! I changed the server.port to 443 but now I no longer access my website.

Error for differents browsers: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: @A-d-r-i, thanks for the update.  Your (top-level) answer is correct.  The TLS config needs to be in the global scope along with `server.port = 443`.  (In the upcoming lighttpd 1.4.60, this will be more forgiving.)